# OpenVPN issue in virtual machines only

Tags: virtualbox, openvpn

I use VirtualBox VMs to emulate a server and a client for development purpose.
The VMs networks are in bridged mode.
Both server and client are running Debian and use OpenVPN.

Open VPN is configured to use tcp-server protocol.
It works just fine with physical computers, but in my VMs the tunnel isn't established unless I change the protocol for udp. I don't get why I have this issue only with virtual machines.
It is quite bothersome and I am searching for an explanation/solution.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: Have you tried running tcpdump or Wireshark on Client and Server to make sure TCP packets are being received? Are there relevant log entries? Btw.: UDP should be the preferred protocol for a VPN, cf. TCP-over-TCP https://openvpn.net/faq/what-is-tcp-meltdown/

Comment: No I didn't tried that yet. We use a custom distro based on Debian and I am not the one who made the configuration of the VPN, I am just using the thing as it is. The person who made it is quite skilled in general so I guess there is a good reason why he choose tcp. I didn't see anything relevant in logs but I am not really an expert. I will continue to investigate, thanks.